# Multiple relations with mongoid wrapper

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, mongoid, relationship, database

i have following problem:

i have 3 models orders, users and apps, with following relations:

Users:

```
has_many :apps
has_many :orders
```

Orders:

```
belongs_to :user
has_one :app
```

Apps:

```
belongs_to :user
belongs_to :app
```

based on these models, i want to make the following queries with mongoid (rails mongodb-wrapper):

```
@order = current_user.orders.new(...)
@app = @order.build_app()
```

the result should be, that an new app and order is created, where the order has an app_id and an user_id and the new app gets just a user_id. what it actually does is, that it creates a new order and new app, but only with an user_id in the order, the new app stays untouched.

any advice? thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The new app should have an order_id but not a user id with the way you coded it. Also, if you want them to persist you need to create instead of build.

```
order = current_user.orders.create
current_user.apps.create(order: order)
```

The only ids that will be set are those that are part of the relation used for the build/create. Anything else needs to be passed in.

Comment: current_user.apps.create will set the appropriate id for that relation, so it should be good to go.